# resample() DataFrame for one Series, while copying values of all other Series in DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I want to resample on one Series in a DataFrame, where all other Series in the DataFrame have identical data for each index. I can resample the one Series in question, but how do I copy the data over?

#### Setup

If I begin with `df`:

```
                    value    data_1 data_2  data_3  data_4
effective_date                                            
2018-7-31        4.010784  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-8-31        2.044298  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-10-31      11.493831  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-11-30      13.929844  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-12-31      21.500490  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
```

And want to add in the September date with a value of `0` and all other data remaining the same:

```
                    value    data_1 data_2  data_3  data_4
effective_date                                            
2018-7-31        4.010784  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-8-31        2.044298  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-9-30        0.000000  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-10-31      11.493831  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-11-30      13.929844  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-12-31      21.500490  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
```

#### Code so far

I can resample `value` with the following code:

```
df.value.resample('M').first().fillna(0)
```

To get:

```
effective_date
2018-07-31     4.010784
2018-08-31     2.044298
2018-09-30     0.000000
2018-10-31    11.493831
2018-11-30    13.929844
2018-12-31    21.500490
```

What's the most efficient way to copy the other values into `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resample the whole DataFrame with `resample`, then fill NA's for 'value' column with 0's and `ffill` all other columns:

```
df.resample('M').first().fillna({'value': 0}).ffill()
```

Output:

```
                    value      data_1 data_2  data_3  data_4
effective_date                                              
2018-07-31       4.010784  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-08-31       2.044298  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-09-30       0.000000  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-10-31      11.493831  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-11-30      13.929844  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-12-31      21.500490  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
```

Comment: I've asked an additional, but related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305997/resample-over-multiindex

Answer (score 1):

After `resample` , you can just change you value by `where`

```
s=df.resample('M').ffill()
s.value=s.value.where(s.index.isin(df.index),0)
s
Out[249]: 
                    value    data_1 data_2  data_3  data_4
effective_date                                            
2018-07-31       4.010784  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-08-31       2.044298  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-09-30       0.000000  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-10-31      11.493831  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-11-30      13.929844  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
2018-12-31      21.500490  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
```